# How to append a new Json element to setData with resultJsonFactory in Magento2

Tags: magento2, zend-framework, json

```
public function __construct(
   JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
)
{
   $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
}
$response = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
$response->setHttpResponseCode(406);
$response->setData(['error_code' => '111','subscription' => '222']);
...
// now i want to add new_item to the array in response 
// without clearing the previous set content. 
$response->setData('new_item' => '333')
```

I can see that `setData` it is using `Zend_Json::encode`

```
public function setData($data, $cycleCheck = false, $options = [])
{
    $this->json = \Zend_Json::encode($data, $cycleCheck, $options);
    return $this;
}
```

but I can't find if it is an option to insert instead of set

Answer (score 0):

```
public function setData($data, $cycleCheck = false, $options = [])
{
    $this->json = \Zend_Json::encode($data, $cycleCheck, $options);
    return $this;
}
```

As we can see, when trying to set json data, the previous data are always overridden by the new data.

In your case, we can try to use a variable data array. For example:

```
$response = [
            'errors' => false
        ];

//Condition 1

$response = ['errors' = true, 'error_code' => '111','subscription' => '222']

//Condition 2

$response['new_item'] = 3333;
...
//Final Condition
...

//Set final data

$response->setData($response);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answer but the code in condition 2 will give and error and your solution don't add an element to the current array.  i can see debugging that the data is in a json method inside the class but my problem is to get the body in magento (no js) and add the new element and setData again with the new value

Comment: Thanks, my mistake. Just edited my answer.

Comment: thanks but still if I undertood your approach is to convert the json into an array and add a new element and setData again but i don't see any method inthe json factory object to render the body. thats why i can't accept the solution

Answer (score 0):

Some years late but you can use following workaround for what you needed : )

```php
    /** @var  \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterfaceFactory $responseFactory */
    $response = $responseFactory->create();
    $result->renderResult($response);
    $resultData = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
    //manipulate data as needed and set it again
    $result->setData($resultData);
```